# Python print all binary numbers from 000 - 111

Tags: python, performance, binary

I needed to produce all the binary numbers from 000-111 in string form and my first approach is shown below. However, it struck me that this must be a very inefficient way to do this. Are there better ways please, and how are they more efficient?

```
 # print all binary numbers from 000 - 111
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            for k in range(2):
                value = f'{i}{j}{k}'
                print(value)
```

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate of the linked question. I'm asking for a way to produce multiple binary values in an efficient way, while the other question just addresses a single conversion.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
for i in range(8):
    s = bin(i)[2:]
    print(s.zfill(3))
```

**Output**

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Comment: OK, but is it more efficient "under the hood" and if so why please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this;

```
>>> ['{:03b}'.format(i) for i in range(8)]
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']

>>> ['{:03b}'.format(i) for i in range(2,8)]
['010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

Just will have to convert the range to decimal.

Comment: You can change the format specifier to `'{:03b}'`  to exactly match op's output.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few different ways to do it, and their results. The performance difference is minor in the grand scheme of things, so you shouldn't worry too much.

```
%%timeit
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(2):
            value = f'{i}{j}{k}'
            print(value)
```

Original Result: `823 µs ± 49.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

```
%%timeit
for i in range(8):
    print("{0:03b}".format(i))
```

Result: `784 µs ± 35.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

```
%%timeit  
for i in range(8):    
    print(bin(i)) #note that this does not produce the output exactly as you'd want it
```

Result: `807 µs ± 36.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

```
%%timeit 
for i in range(8): 
    print(bin(i)[2:].rjust(3, '0')) #this one really surprised me, i didn't expect it to be fastest.
```

Result: `773 µs ± 43.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

And just an itertools version if you didn't want to use binary representations. Note that i have excluded library import for the sake of comparison.

```
from itertools import product
bits = ['0', '1']
%%timeit
for i in product(bits, repeat = 3):
    print(''.join(i))
```

Result: `801 µs ± 65.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`